# Model resource ownership in a flat structure

Tags: mysql, database-design, mysql-8.0

I have a database model with different entities related to each other, but in the end they all have to be 'owned' by the master entity which in this case is the Organization.

I was wondering if it is a good practice to add the Organization ID as foreign key to every single table so that when doing a query I can simply add the Organization ID inside the where clause and know that I am in fact querying the correct Organization and not someone else's data.

On top of this I will have an administrative interface to manage each and every entity separately, but again, if those entities are not explicitly related to the organization I won't be able to tell if I'm allowed to access them and if they belong to me (the Organization). So it's kind of like a flat structure for the most part.

Comment: @J.D. I'm using MySQL v8.0